# Make query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nest, arrayobject

I'm learning elastic for a new project.
I have a index with format:

```
{
    "content_id": "bbbbbb",
    "title": "content 2",
    "data": [
            {
              "id": "xx",
              "value": 3,
              "tags": ["a","b","c"]
            },
            {
              "id": "yy",
              "value": 1,
              "tags": ["e","d","c"]
            }
   ]
}
```

How can i make a query to search contents that have at least one element in **data** that include tags **"a" and "b"**  ?

thanks so much !!

How can i make query or re design my format data to easy make new query ?

Answer (score 0):

Working with lists and nested documents in Elasticsearch is a bit tricky.

When creating the index, you need to specify the mapping for the nested documents. You can do this by [adding a mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#mappings) for the data field.

```
PUT /my_index

{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have already created the index, you should [delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) it first, then create it again with the mapping.

Before deleting the index, you can [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) (copy) the data to a new index.

Now you can query the data field using the nested query:

```
GET /my_index/_search

{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
                "terms": {
                    "data.tags": [
                        "j",
                        "b",
                        "c"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "doc" in mappings, can I  ignore it ? @ChamRun

Comment: @quang-lê It is the `type` of the document. You can use any name you want. I think it has been removed in the latest version of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to get the document if at least one object in `data` contains **`a` and `b` both**, then you need to specify the `nested` mapping as suggested by @ChamRun.

But for getting the results having **`a` and `b` both**, you need to use the below query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "data.tags": "a"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "data.tags": "b"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```